# How to handle a json returning data objects with firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android application which does the following:

```
com.google.firebase.database.Query query = mUsersRef
            .orderByChild(USER_TABLE_EMAIL)
            .startAt(searchTerm)
            .endAt(searchTerm + FirebaseConstants.SEARCH_ESCAPE);

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot d = dataSnapshot;

            getView().showSearchResults();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // TODO: something?
        }
    });
```

I was wondering what the simplest way to convert `dataSnapshot` into `User` objects was. Do I need to get returned json and do some form of conversion? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your data snapshot into an object as shown below:

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for(DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           User user = snapShot.getValue(User.class);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // TODO: something?
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i wanted. wish the docs were a little easier to sift through